# ildasm / ilasm - Symantec false positive

Tags: decompiling, ildasm, ilasm, symantec

I am having a problem with disassembling and reassembling a .NET executable and it throwing a false positive after.

The error I get specifically is:

> Heur.AdvML.B

As of now, I am no longer editing the asm prior to re-compiling it. I literally de-compile it and recompile it, run it and get the error. I am aware that I can attempt to reach out to my network admin to get a folder removed from the "watch" list, as well as attempt to contact Symantec.

What would be ideal, is if someone could help me identify why exactly this is occurring.

Things I have tried:

Strip all debugging references from the asm completely
Set System.Diagnostics.DebuggableAttribute/DebuggingModes with 01 00 02 00 00 00 00, which should be release-optimized indicator
de-compile and re-compile a known working exe without touching it

What is causing this false positive if the original `exe` is clean. Do I need to sign the `exe`? Really confused any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. When recompiling with ilasm.exe, you need to pass in the .res file that is generated by ildasm.exe during decompile. Just add the following parameter to your ilasm arguments:

```
/RESOURCE=file.res
```